# Incorrect timezone with NSCalendar

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nstimezone

I am attempting to grab a date using a specified timezone name, for example "America/New_York". For some reason, when I choose my correct timezone "America/Chicago", it shows the correct time (e.g. 9:41PM). However, when I choose New York, it should show an hour ahead (expecting 10:41PM), but I get an hour behind my current time (what I get: 8:41PM).

```
- (NSDate*)dateFromTimezone:(NSTimeZone*)timezone
{
    timezone = ( timezone == nil ? [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:CUSTOMTIMEZONE] : timezone );

    NSDate * date = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendarUnit units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:timezone];
    [gregorian components:units fromDate:date];

    NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units fromDate:date];
    [dateComponents setTimeZone:timezone];
    [dateComponents setCalendar:gregorian];

    return [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
}
```

Comment: I've studied your code for 5 minutes and I cannot tell what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you ignore the return value to the call `[gregorian components:units fromDate:date];`?

Comment: I am trying to get the date for a timezone that I am passing through this method. As the original text says, the date for timezone that is passed is not the correct time/date using the example here.

Comment: NSDate does not have a time zone, so the approach doesn't make sense. There's literally no possible return value that would do what you want since you're returning an object that doesn't include the concept of a time zone. What do you actually want to do with the result?